# How to update the data source after updating the data grid view in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview, datasource

I am adding a delete function in my data grid view at the moment.
I add the delete button by code, and I plan to trigger the delete function via Event.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //if click is on new row or header row
        if (e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex || e.RowIndex < 0)
            return;

        //Check if click is on specific column 
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["dataGridViewDeleteButton"].Index)
        {
            
            System.Console.WriteLine("delete button pressed!");
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);

            
        }
    }
```

I have been tested the function, the `debug` console actually prints out the `delete button pressed!`, which means the Event is triggered successfully.
However, I am running into an issue; how to update the underline data source after I removed the cell at specific row?
The data source code is :

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
// data loading ...
```

Comment: The datasource does not automatically get repainted.  The trick is to set the datasource to null and back to original datasource : dataGridView1.DataSource = null; dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;

Comment: I tested your code in my project, and everything works fine, the dataTable will also be automatically updated (delete the specified row). So, did you declare the `dataTable` as a global variable?

Comment: Yeah I did. I am a bit confused regarding the DataGridView, do you mean it will update the data source automatically?

Comment: @Nan How did you get the dataTable? Programmatically or from a database? In my test, I create a datatable programmatically  and filled with data. Then it will update automatically.

Comment: Programmatically. It I was a csv file in the beginning and I export the data into the date table for the demonstration purposes.  Can you please put down your code in the solution and let me have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Nan Have posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my test.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    testdgv.CellClick += testdgv_CellClick;
}

DataTable table = new DataTable();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));

    table.Rows.Add(1, "KKK", "Des1");
    table.Rows.Add(2, "YYY", "Des2");
    table.Rows.Add(3, "LLL", "Des3");
    table.Rows.Add(4, "EEE", "Des4");
    table.Rows.Add(5, "TTT", "Des5");

    testdgv.DataSource = table;
}

private void testdgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // if Description clicked, delete the row
    if (e.ColumnIndex == testdgv.Columns["Description"].Index)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("delete button pressed!");
        testdgv.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    }
}

// test
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string ID = table.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(ID);
    }
}
```

Test result:

[image]